Relationship in Mongoose
Im trying to get value from relationship like if bookSchema.producer= ProducerSchema.id, so, i will get value is string from ProducerSchema.nameProducer. I can get value from both but have no ideas how to do relations ship. Its could be easier if i use mysql or MS SQL, but im new at MongoDB.
Here is my code.
const bookSchema= new db.Schema({
    id:Number,
    nameBook:String,
    prices:Number,
    region:Boolean,
    producer: {
        type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'producerS',
    },
    moTA:String,
    urlImages:String
},{versionKey:false});


const ProducerSchema = new db.bookSchema({
    id: Number,
    nameProducer: String   
},{versionKey:false});



const producerS= db.model('produceRs', ProducerSchema );


const bookS =db.model('booKs',bookSchema);


const listBook=async()=>{
    try{
        const list = await bookS.find({}).populate('producer');;
        return list;
    }catch(error){
        throw error;
    }
}

and output value
<% sachs.forEach(s => { %>
                <tr>
                    <th><%= s.id %></th> //worked
                    <td><%= s.nameBook%></td> //worked
                    <td><%= s.prices%></td> //work
                    <td><%= s.producer%></td> //not worked <!-- im also use s.producer.nameProducer but its ping not define -->
                    <td><%= s.region== 1 ? "A" : "B" %></td>
                </tr>
                <% }) %>

Sorry for my bad english.
Im tried some solutions but seem didnt work at all.

I am assuming you want to get the name of the producer when you query for book/s from the bookschema. If this is the case, you can add the ref value in the field. The ref value should be the name that is exported from the model.
const Producer= db.model('Producer', ProducerSchema );
module.exports = Producer

Do check the export name
const bookSchema= new db.Schema({
    id:Number,
    nameBook:String,
    prices:Number,
    region:Boolean,
    producer: {
        type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Producer',
    },
    moTA:String,
    urlImages:String
},{versionKey:false});

Now to get the name of the producer, you can use populate query.
In some cases, you need to import the model at the top for populate to work, depending on the version of mongoose/mongo used.
